# Метод который ищет индекс второго ненулевого элемента

Tags: java

Метод который ищет индекс( с нуля) второго ненулевого элемента , рядом с которым (слева или справа) находиться значение 0. Если в массиве нет двух таких элементов, вернуть -1.
Например : при {1,3,7,0,5,4} возвращает 4, {5,6,0,0,0,2,2,3,0,6} возвращает 5, {0,1,2,3} возвращает -1;[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Почти получилось сделать, проблема только с тем, чтобы возвращался -1 в нужных случаях.

```
public static int task1(int[] arr) {
        int finder = 0;
        if (arr.length == 1){
            return -1;
        }
        else{
            for( int i = 1; i<arr.length-1;i++){
                if(arr[i]!=0 && arr[i-1]==0 ){
                    finder = i;
                }
            }
        }

        return finder;
    }
```

Comment: Задача не слишком понятна.  Почему `{1,3,7,0,5,4} возвращает 4`, а не 3?

Comment: Вероятней всего проблема решается инициализацией finder c 0 на -1 в начале функции.

Comment: @NowhereMan 3 - это индекс нуля , а нам нужно число идущее после нуля( то есть 4).

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int task1(int[] arr) {
    int finder = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == 0) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count <= 1) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (arr.length == 1){
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        for( int i = 1; i<arr.length-1;i++){
            if(arr[i]!=0 && arr[i-1]==0 ){
                finder = i;
            }
        }
    }

    return finder;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но метод работает не совсем правильно.Я понял вашу идею, но ведь возможна ситуация где будет один ноль в массиве, но он будет в середине и тогда у этого нуля уже будет 2 соседа. Например: при {1,3,7,0,5,4} должно возвращать 4, а ваш метод возвращает -1